# Disk seen by BIOS but not seen by Ubuntu and removed from software RAID 5 config

Tags: raid, disk

Here is what my server is seeing

```
  *-disk
       description: SCSI Disk
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sdc
       configuration: sectorsize=4096
```

The disk is detected by the BIOS, I just checked that but for some reasons it is not visible to Ubuntu. How do I fix this? (I guess the above should be fixed before even attempting to add the disk back to md0 -RAID)